# search in html file and show it in the list

Tags: android, search, webview

I'm trying to search a word in all html files which are stored in my project assets folder. But my method is only searching in current html file.

```
findBox = new EditText(this);
    findBox.setMinEms(30);
    findBox.setSingleLine(true);
    findBox.setHint("Ara...");
    findBox.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))) {
                wv.findAll(findBox.getText().toString());
                try {
                    // Can't use getMethod() as it's a private method
                    for (Method m : WebView.class.getDeclaredMethods()) {
                        if (m.getName().equals("setFindIsUp")) {
                            m.setAccessible(true);
                            m.invoke(wv, true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception ignored) {
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: `But my method is only searching in current html file.` As it should. WebView.findAll() searches the current document. Your code clearly does nothing with assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how WebView works. When you load a html document with a:

```
WebView wv;
// ... some initialization here
wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/page.html");
```

It loads just one particular page, it won't help you find content in all html files in assets.

Regarding searching through all the files:

1) get all file names in assets dir or some sub dir in it. In the example below I get all the files in a `/assets/html`:

```
String dirFrom = "html"
AssetManager am = res.getAssets();
String fileList[] = am.list(dirFrom);
```

2) open an InputStream for each file and use it to search through its contents, similarly to this

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("test.txt");
```

3) Then you will know the file names, their locations and ofc if you want to have everything displayed in WebView now you can just load each file with `loadUrl`.

On a side note I've noticed you are using:

> public int findAll (String find)

And you should:

> public void findAllAsync (String find)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can search all files, with your algorithm. Actually ı want to store words which we find in html files with their file name and show a listview. But findAllAsync() is insufficient for it. Can you help me in this matter?

Comment: - Scan all the `html` files in `assets` directory in search of a string
- Show which files contain the search result in a `ListView`

WebView's method `findAllAsync()` is used to perform a browser-like find. Like let's say in Firefox where you use `ctrl-F` to find something and it allows you to jump between results. It won't return you any info other then number of results found + `findNext()` will scroll the WebView to the next result.